# if:true comparison inside the for loop

Tags: salesforce, lwc

I want to do comparison in the `if:true` part inside `for:each` loop.
The answer I got from google is to create a new sub-component. But I really don't wanna go this route... Any other good options?

```
      <template for:each={listData} for:item="obj">
                                 <template if:true={obj.Id == CurrentId}>
      </template>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_directives)

> **if:true|false={expression}**
> Use this directive to conditionally render DOM elements in a template.
> The expression can be a JavaScript identifier (for example, person) or dot notation that accesses a property from an object (person.firstName). **The engine doesn’t allow computed expressions (person[2].name['John'])**. To compute the value of expression, use a getter in the JavaScript class.

You can't use these kind of expression, but you can add to your object a property or a getter that evaluates to a boolean. Something like this:

```js
this.listData = this.listData.map((elem) => {
    const self = this;
    return {
        ...elem,
        get isCurrent() {
             return this.Id == self.CurrentId;
        }
    };
});
```

Then you can use `<template if:true={obj.isCurrent}>`.